# RowIndex of row of which dropdown was selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

[image]
Reference image of the GV

**So OnSelectedIndexChanged of the dropdown in 7th cell I want to enable or disable the Remarks column (last column) of that row**

Gridview.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdassetslist" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" BackColor="Transparent" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Dashed" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4"
                         DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateSelectButton="true" CellSpacing="2" OnRowDataBound="grdassetslist_RowDataBound" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#66ccff"
                          OnSelectedIndexChanged="grdassetslist_SelectedIndexChanged" HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-CssClass="grd" RowStyle-CssClass="grd" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="15"
                     OnPageIndexChanged="grdassetslist_PageIndexChanged" OnPageIndexChanging="grdassetslist_PageIndexChanging">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField Visible="false" >
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnAstID" runat="server" Visible="false" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Code" HeaderText="Asset Category" ReadOnly="true" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="SAPAssetCode" HeaderText="SAP Asset Code" ReadOnly="true" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ITAssetCode" HeaderText="IT Asset Code" ReadOnly="true" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Make" HeaderText="Make" ReadOnly="true" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ModelNo" HeaderText="ModelNo" ReadOnly="true" />                            
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="InvoiceDate" HeaderText="Invoice Date" ReadOnly="true" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="AssetStatus" HeaderText="Current Status" ReadOnly="true" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Change Status To">
                                
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_each_asset_status" runat="server" Width="100px" Height="25px" CssClass="dd" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_each_asset_status_SelectedIndexChanged1" CausesValidation="false" ></asp:DropDownList>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="CurrentUser" HeaderText="CurrentUser" ReadOnly="true" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remarks for Status change">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtrmrks" runat="server" placeholder="Remarks (if any)" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="Assests" HeaderText="" ReadOnly="true" />--%>
                        </Columns>
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"/>  
                        <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" /> 
                    </asp:GridView>
```

GridLoad.apx.cs

```
con.Open();
                DropDownList DropDownList1 = (e.Row.FindControl("ddl_each_asset_status") as DropDownList);

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ID,Code[Title] from tbl_assetstatus (nolock) where ID<>2 and IsActive=1 order by ID", con);
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                con.Close();
                DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;

                DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Title";
                DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ID";
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
                DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Status", "0"));
```

SelectedIndexChanged event:

```
protected void ddl_each_asset_status_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Code to Enable or Disable the remarks column of that row of which the dropdown was changed?
            
        }
```

Please add the code for SelectedIndexChanged for this.

**Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 0):

If you using GridView, then I doubt this is a .net core application?

And really, to help us out here - try posting at LEAST SOME of  your gridviewe markup, as then we not trying to play a game of darts in a room with the lights out.

Assuming a GV like this:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataKeyNames="ID"
            CssClass="table table=table-hover" Width="800px"
         OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">

            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Firstname" HeaderText="First name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select Hotel City">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="cboCity" runat="server" Width="120px" Height="26px"
                            DataTextField="City"
                            DataValueField="City"
                            AutoPostBack="true"
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboCity_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="Hotel Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        </div>


        <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px">
            <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Height="179px" Width="450px" TextMode="MultiLine">

            </asp:Label>

        </div>
```

Code to load:

```
    DataTable rstCity = new DataTable();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }

    void LoadData()
    {

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL =
                "SELECT City FROM City ORDER BY City";
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                rstCity.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());

                cmdSQL.CommandText = 
                    "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName";
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

Ok, and now the code for the combo box (dropdown list). We assume auto-post back, so the code is thus this:

```
    protected void cboCity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList cboCity = (DropDownList)sender;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)cboCity.NamingContainer;
        int PK = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"];

        string cr = System.Environment.NewLine;
        string sResult =
            $"Row index = {gRow.RowIndex} \n DataBase PK = {PK} <br/>" +
            $" Hotel = {gRow.Cells[3].Text} <br/>" +
            $"Combo Box selection = {cboCity.Text}";

        lbl1.Text = sResult;
    }
```

and thus we see/get this:

[image]

## Edit2:

I should also note the following additonal information:

Of course I have to fill/load the drop down.. and that is done in row data bound event. Eg this:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRowView gData = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

            DropDownList cboCity = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("cboCity");
            cboCity.DataSource = rstCity;
            cboCity.DataBind();
            cboCity.Items.Insert(0,new ListItem("Select", ""));
            if (gData["City"] !=  DBNull.Value)
            {
                cboCity.Text = gData["City"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, note how I don't care (or bother) with the GV selected index changed event. I really don't need it. I as noted, simple set autopost-back = true.

Last but not least?

you of course cannot build ANY working webforms page if you attemptto load up data in on-load but FORGET to check isPostback.

Since any button click, any post-back, or anything causing a post-back will of course trigger the page load event again, and BEFORE any of your other events. Thus, you need to ALWAYS ensure that you only load up the information one time on page load, since if you re-load the gv, or even a dropdown, then you tend to lose that choice by the user being made.

thus, that all imporant !IsPostBack stub is required for most pages.

Eg this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }
```

next up:

Since the dropdown list has the one grid row, then you are free to get data, hide data, enable or do whatever you please.

Just keep in mind that

For built in "databound" columns, you use the cells[] colleciton.

For any templated control, then you use gRow.FindControl("control name here")

So, since your "goal" in question is to operate on "txtrmrks" then that is a templated column, and thus we have to use findcontrol.

Say, like this:

air code warning!!!

```
    protected void cboCity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList cboCity = (DropDownList)sender;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)cboCity.NamingContainer;

        TextBox txtrmrks = (TextBox)gRow.FindControl("txtrmrks");

        if (cboCity.Text == "Banff")
        {
            // disable the txtrmrks box
            txtrmrks.Enabled = false;

        }
    }
```

You also not clear if you are going to working the value returned from the cbo box as "id", or "Title"

I suggest this way, and not to use ".Text" of the cbo, but this:

```
cboCity.SelectedItem.Value   (gets value - ID)
cboCity.SelectedItem.Text   (gets Text - Title)


            if (cboCity.SelectedItem.Text)
```

Comment: Hi, I've added more on the question and the GV code. Please check if this is correct

Comment: See my edit2 for further details - but yes, your code for the most part seems on the right track.